# One project and 2 clickonce distributives

Tags: clickonce

My project use ClickOnce for deployment. I need create 2 clickonce packages for client and server with differents .config files. Now, before publish, I twice change publish properties with changes output folder and url for client and server and with edit config. 
What the best way for automate my works?

Answer (score 0):

NAnt/MsBuild should become your best friends. Both have a task dedicated to build/publish VS projects. You just create 4 tasks then:

1. update project config files
2. build/deploy ClickOnce for the first time
3. update project config files
4. build/deploy ClickOnce for the second time

Answer (score 0):

I asked for a feature update to ClickOnce on MS Connect about six months ago, which would allow for such a change.  In my case, I was wanting to have the ability to publish to two separate server locations, however, I specifically asked for multiple, publication profiles.

Microsoft's response wasn't what I wanted but they did provide a work-around.  Effectively, you will need to create two projects, the second links to the first and you can modify the publication settings of the second project as you see fit.

See my [MS Connect post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/660685/allow-clickonce-applications-to-be-published-to-a-secondary-test-location) for further, more detailed instructions.  I'll admit, this isn't a great answer but it's probably the easiest option.